# Putting a textbox directly below another textbox in the same cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

I am creating a calendar feature which takes inputs from a form and based off that I will assign into a dynamic calendar.

The problem is that my third textbox and subsequent textbox will not be directly below the previous textbox created.
[image: Calendar Image].

It is created in the position of the second textbox. How can I calculate the bottom position of the last created textbox?

Also how can I code it to automatically increase the row height accordingly when there is more than one textbox.

```vb
If Not searchCell Is Nothing Then
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim targetColumn As Long
    targetRow = searchCell.row
    targetColumn = searchCell.Column
    
    For Each targetCell In searchRange
        If IsDate(targetCell.Value) Then
            Dim currentDate As Date
            currentDate = DateValue(targetCell.Value)
            
            ' Compare currentDate with SVDateValue (day and month)
            If Day(currentDate) = Day(searchDate) And Month(currentDate) = Month(searchDate) Then
                'MsgBox currentDate
                'MsgBox Day(searchDate)
                'MsgBox Month(currentDate)
                'MsgBox Month(searchDate)
            
                ' Find the original textbox, if any
                Dim originalTextbox As Shape
                For Each originalTextbox In calendarSheet.Shapes
                    If originalTextbox.Type = msoTextBox Then ' Check if the shape is a textbox
                        If originalTextbox.TopLeftCell.row = targetRow And originalTextbox.TopLeftCell.Column = targetColumn Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next originalTextbox
                                
                ' Calculate the top position for the new textbox (below the original)
                Dim topPosition As Double
                If Not originalTextbox Is Nothing Then
                    topPosition = originalTextbox.Top + originalTextbox.Height + 1 ' Add some spacing
                Else
                    topPosition = calendarSheet.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Top
                End If
                
                Dim tb As Shape
                Set tb = calendarSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                  Left:=calendarSheet.Cells(targetCell.row, targetCell.Column).Left, _
                  Top:=topPosition, _
                  Width:=calendarSheet.Cells(targetCell.row, targetCell.Column).Width, _
                  Height:=80)

                'Height:=calendarSheet.Cells(targetCell.row, targetCell.Column).Height) Automatic Fit to Box
                
                ' Set properties for the TextBox
                tb.Fill.Transparency = 1 ' Fully transparent fill
                tb.Line.Visible = msoFalse ' No border
                
                ' Set TextBox text to SVDate and company values
                tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = SVDateValue & vbCrLf & DPValue & vbCrLf & companyValue & vbCrLf & SVTimeValue

                ' Change color of SVDateValue text to white
                'tb.TextFrame2.textRange.Characters(1, Len(SVDateValue)).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, Len(SVDateValue)).Font.Fill.Visible = msoFalse 'Making ServiceDate Color to Not Filled
            End If
        End If
    Next targetCell
    
    ' Update the month and year cells
    'calendarSheet.Range("D1").Value = extractedMonth
    'calendarSheet.Range("G1").Value = extractedYear
    
Else
    MsgBox "Date not found in the specified range.", vbExclamation
End If
```

Comment: The bottom of the textbox should be the Top + Height.

Comment: Yes i tried that also but like i will be using the original top + height and i cant get like the previous textbox top + height. If possible can u rewrite and show me to allow me to better understand and see from there. Appreciate Very Much

Comment: Since you use one cell for one date, set the cell value to the count of events and hide them (e.g. color=backcolor). With this can fast calculate the next position based on the cell coordinates and the count of textboxes.

Comment: but the problem im facing is cause i want these 3 textbox created is in the same cell since they are in the same dates but i have problems referring to the previous textbox bottom value. How can i get the previous textbox bottom value

Comment: `Cells(x,y).Top + TextBox.Height * n` , where n is the count of the textboxes.

Comment: If you're looking for the previous values, just assign them variables when they are valid and use the variables as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code shows how to add TextBoxes which is next to each other and adjust their anchor cell height.

> Question: how can i code it so like it will automatically increase the row height accordingly when there is more then 1 textbox.

> Answer:
> Compare the TextBox top position plus height to the anchor cell row height. Adjust the row height as needed, up to the 409.1 maximum.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim anchorCell As Range, i As Integer
    Dim objShp As Shape
    Dim topPos, leftPos, widthTxt, heightTxt, endPos
    ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete
    Set anchorCell = [c1]
    widthTxt = 150 ' TextBox width
    heightTxt = 50 ' TextBox height
    For i = 0 To 2 ' Add 3 TextBox in anchorCell
        ' TextBox top-left location
        topPos = anchorCell.Top + i * heightTxt
        leftPos = anchorCell.Left
        ' Add TextBox
        Set objShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                leftPos, topPos, widthTxt, heightTxt)
        objShp.Placement = xlFreeFloating
    Next
    ' Adjust archor cell to fit TextBox
    endPos = topPos + heightTxt
    If anchorCell.Height < topPos + heightTxt Then
        ' Max row height is 409.1
        anchorCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = IIf(endPos < 409.1, endPos, 409.1)
    End If
End Sub
```